# Write an image file to just one partition of usb flash drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, iso-image, bootable-media

I want to burn an image to a USB flash drive that I have partitioned.  All the imaging programs I have tried format the entire drive, erasing the partition.  I have also tried to resize the partition after the burn is complete, but this always results in the drive not being bootable at that point.   Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What imaging programs have you tried?  I use Acronis and it has the capability to image a single partition, and restore that image, to a single partition.  The software from the major competition to Acronis also support doing that.  The alternative is to restore the image to the drive, then create additional partitions manually on the drive, then create a new image of the flash drive.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. Writable images already have a partition table inside, so they have to be written directly to a storage device. You can't nest a partition table inside a partition.

If you want to UEFI boot (as opposed to BIOS booting), most images can be used by simply copying their contents to a FAT32-formatted partition manually. I don't think this counts as "writing the image", but I assume you care more about the effect than technical details.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this on a usb thumb drive.

First backup your data because writng a bootable image file will erase whatever you are writing to.

Second run a partition manager. You should be able to see the image you just wrote.

There should be a bunch of free space on the drive.

Create a new partition using the free space. Make sure the start byte for the partition is greater than the image file size.

Once you have built the partition, copy your data into that partition.

I am on a Linux Manjaro Plasma system. Not sure if that matters. I use it so I can boot up and reinstall the operating system if necessary.

I just tested the data and boot on that drive. It still works.

Looking at Partition Manager, the first partition is the image file - 3.56 GB, Second is a fat12 partition - 4 MB. Not sure what it is for but something in the process automatically put it there. There is 140 KB of something in it though. I don't remember. Third is an ext4 data partition - 228.1 GB. I use that for backing up my hard drive data.

The only issue with this is that to update the image file on the usb drive you have to repeat the process, so I don't do it often.

Apart from that it is very reliable.

USB drive partitions

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FWLT.jpg

Comment: And what does _"copy your data into that partition"_ mean exactly? Nested partitions wouldn't work. Guessing based on the rest of your post I think you've actually written the image directly to the device rather than a partition, overwriting the partition you've created with partition table in the image. This is completely normal (except for manually creating the partition that will get destroyed anyway) and not what this question is about.